# Linux: top not showing/counting all tasks

Tags: linux, kernel

Running top I see the total tasks being about 81 (line 2):

```
top - 21:16:18 up 23 days,  1:47,  2 users,  load average: 0.06, 0.03, 0.01
Tasks:  81 total,   1 running,  55 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.3%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   1008824k total,   606424k used,   402400k free,   164676k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   310044k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  SWAP COMMAND
    1 root      20   0 19692 2552 2220 S  0.0  0.3   0:04.54    0 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00    0 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 I  0.0  0.0   0:00.00    0 kworker/0:0
...
```

The line `Tasks:  81 total,   1 running,  55 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie`  shows a total of 81 with 1 running and 55 sleeping. Where are the others?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420320/why-does-total-tasks-listed-in-top-command-output-not-equal-running-sleeping

Answer (score 1):

**you can do the following to list all the processes:**

```
top -b -n1
```

In the above, we are outputting all of the processes from top to display from 1 iteration in batch mode.

`-b` is for batch mode

`-n` is for the number of iterations to run top in batch mode

**if you only wanted the idle processes, specifically, you could do:**

```
top -b -n1 -i
```

`-i` is to list the idle processes

From the [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html)

> **-b**  :Batch-mode operation
> Starts top in Batch mode, which could be useful for sending >output from top to other programs or to a file.  In this mode, top will not accept input and runs until the iterations limit you've set with the `-n' command-line option or until killed.

> **-n**  :Number-of-iterations limit as:  -n number
> Specifies the maximum number of iterations, or frames, top should produce before ending.

> **-i**  :Idle-process toggle
> Starts top with the last remembered `i' state reversed.  When this toggle is Off, tasks that have not used any CPU since the last update will not be displayed.  For additional information regarding this toggle  see  topic  4c.  TASK  ARE Commands, SIZE.